# What is the grammatical meaning of ידות (Yados, "hands") as used to mean "one third" in Shas?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, kiddush-hachodesh

Ibn Ezra, in his commentary on Exodus 12:2, says the maximum length of a lunar month is 29 days, half of a day, and two "hands" of a day.

> כ"ט יום וחצי ושני **ידות** שעה

Similar language is used by the Sefer Mitzvos Katan (סמ״ק), Mitzvah 103, where he quotes a version of Rosh Hashana 25a as follows:

> אמר להם ר"ג כך מקובלני מבית אבי אבא שאין חידושה של לבנה פחות מכ"ט יום וחצי ושתי **ידות** וע"ג חלקים

The version of the Talmud we have today uses the language ״שלישי שעה״ (thirds of an hour) suggesting an equivalence.

**My question:** What is the original source for the usage of a "hand" as a measurement equal to a third of an hour and what linguistic significance or meaning does a "hand" have with its usage here as a portion, specifically a third.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No such girsa appears in the friedberg database

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%96

Comment: https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%D7%99_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%9B%D7%97

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Arakhin.8b.17.2?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=bi

Comment: You can find the word yados meaning portion in Tanach here: https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.19.44?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Metzudat_Zion_on_II_Samuel.19.44.1&vhe2=On_Your_Way&lang2=bi